# Comparing lots of data from two tables to find missing data

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, missing-data

I have two tables that I need to compare and find entries that are missing data.

Example:

```
order_table                             rtm_table
----------------------------            ---------------------------------
|Order_id    |    order_cd |            | order_id      |      order_cd |
----------------------------            ---------------------------------
| 60123456   |      1      |            |  60123456     |        1      |
| 60123456   |      2      |            |  60123456     |        2      |
| 60123456   |      3      |            |  60123456     |        3      |
| 60123456   |      4      |            |  60123456     |     missing   |
| 60123456   |      5      |            |  60123456     |     missing   |
| 60123654   |      1      |            |  60123654     |        1      |
| 60123654   |      2      |            |  60123654     |        2      |
| 60123654   |      3      |            |  60123654     |        3      |
| 60123654   |      4      |            |  60123654     |     missing   |
----------------------------            ---------------------------------
```

This is a simplified example as each order number can have thousands of corresponding entries for order_cd.

So I need a query to compare the two tables and return the distinct order_id where any matching order_cd are missing in the rtm_table.

One of the problems is not all orders listed in the order_table will have entries in the rtm_table. So the first thing that would need to happen is to query the rtm_table table for all order_id and so we are only checking ones that exist at all.

I did this:

```
select * from 
       (select order_cd, order_id from order_table where order_cd != 'NET')      
       order_table
FULL OUTER JOIN 
       (select order_cd, order_id from rtm_table where order_suffix != 
       'NET') rtm_table

on order_table.order_cd = rtm_table.order_cd

where rtm_table.order_cd IS NULL
```

I cobbled this together using info from other posts. This returned sort of what I needed except I need it to return the distinct order_id (don't need each listed 1000+ times for each order_cd) and I need to make sure that it is not returning order_id that do not have any entries in the rtm_table at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does 'missing' indicate the row you've shown doesn't exist, or that it exists with a null `order_cd`? Can you ever have records that are only in `rtm_table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are never rows in `rtm_table` that do no exist in `order_table` - that it is always a subset - you could count the records for each `order_id` in both tables and compare them:

```
select o.order_id
from (
  select order_id, count(order_cd) as cnt
  from order_table
  where order_cd != 'NET'
  group by order_id
) o
join (
  select order_id, count(order_cd) as cnt
  from rtm_table
  where order_suffix != 'NET' 
  group by order_id
) r
on r.order_id = o.order_id
and r.cnt < o.cnt;
```

If there are no matching records in `rtm_table` then the join won't match so those won't be included.

You could also use a variation of Gordon Linoff's left join, but based on an interset of the IDs that appear in both tables:

```
select distinct t.order_id
from (
  select order_id from order_table
  where order_cd != 'NET'
  intersect
  select order_id from rtm_table
  where order_suffix != 'NET' 
) t
join order_table o on o.order_id = t.order_id
left join rtm_table r on r.order_id = o.order_id
and r.order_cd = o.order_cd
where r.order_cd is null;
```

Or even `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select distinct o.order_id
from order_table o
where order_cd != 'NET'
and exists (
  select null from rtm_table r
  where r.order_id = o.order_id
  and order_suffix != 'NET' 
)
and not exists (
  select null from rtm_table r
  where r.order_id = o.order_id
  and r.order_cd = o.order_cd
  and order_suffix != 'NET' 
);
```

You may want to try various approaches to see which works best for your tables, indexes and data - you haven't said how many hits vs. misses you're expecting, which may make a significant difference.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all order_id in the order_table have corresponding entries in the rtm_table for all order_id since there are many types of orders that do not have/need that table info. So we essentially need to compare all of the order_cd for all of the order_id that are listed in the rtm table with the same values in the order_table to see if there are things missing.

Comment: @BillDean - that is what all three queries are doing, unless I've misunderstood you. But that will affect which query (of these, or other suggestions) will be most suitable for your data.

Comment: @Dean - you can add the `NET` filters (or whatever else you need) in al the subqueries, if that's what you mean; I was working from the data you showed rather than your query so I missed those.

Answer (score 1):

i would simply use 'minus' - let Oracle do the dirty job for you:

NEW version:

```
select * from rtm_table
minus
select * from order_table
```

OLD version

```
select * from order_table
minus
select * from rtm_table;
```

This seems to work properly for me

Comment: This also doesn't address the "I need to make sure that it is not returning order_id that do not have any entries in the rtm_table at all" part.